# Filtro de pesquisa no Ionic

Tags: ionic, typescript, ionic3

Fiz um filtro para realizar uma pesquisa no Ionic 3. Eis meu código TypeScript:

```
filtrar()
  {

    //Filtra 
      this.auto.storage.get("acesso").then(sessao =>{
         var dados = {"token":123,"rg":sessao.rg, "data": this.filtroData, "tipo": this.filtroTipo};
         this.items = this.eventosProvider.findAfogamento(dados);
      });

  }
```

Porém qualquer usuário logado consegue acessar as informações inseridas pelos demais. Criei um método para isso:

```
exibir(item)
  { 
    item.styleClass = (Number(item.styleClass) == 1)?0:1;
  }
```

O que eu preciso ter no meu método `exibir()` para que somente o usuário logado possa acessar as informações geradas somente por ele?